# How to get user-id or AWS account id via AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

Is there anyway to get UserId or a.k.a. AWS Account ID?

I have checked the documentation but could not locate (...or probably it doesn't exists...) a method call which returns the UserId.

Comment: You mean you want to get the `iam`, right? `[Here's the proper documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html)

Comment: Not really, I am looking for account id. It is located on right hand side when you open AWS Console > My Account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of. There's no way to get it without creating a resource. Many resources have an ARN associated with it. You can extract the Account ID from the ARN, but you'd have to create a resource first.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, Would expect this to be a Common method call as there are plenty of function which requires Account-Id to be passed. Specially modifyImageAttribute :). Creating resources seems to be overkill :)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used the PHP SDK, but AWS have added a `GetCallerIdentity` API call in STS which can give you both the User ID and the Account ID. It's available here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sts-2011-06-15.html#getcalleridentity

```
$result = $client->getCallerIdentity([/* ... */]);
```

Returns:

```
[
  'Account' => '<string>',
  'Arn' => '<string>',
  'UserId' => '<string>',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You CAN, actually, extract account-id from User's ARN. Without creating any "additional" resources, as IAM User is already an Resource.

[GetUser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html) call on IAM Client. Then parse the ARN string by pattern.